# Images on JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I got a problem, I was practicing on programming in Java a program that displays the java GUI with some text and an image
The problem is that no images are displayed and I can't understand why
Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DON extends JFrame {
   private JPanel panel;

   public DON() {
        //Impostazioni finestra
        JFrame finestra = new JFrame("Title of page");
        finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        finestra.setLayout(null);
        finestra.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        finestra.setResizable(false);
        finestra.setVisible(true);
        finestra.setSize(1280, 720);

        //Impostazioni pannello


        JPanel pannello = new JPanel();
        pannello.setBounds(450, 0, 200 , 30);
        pannello.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
        startPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280 , 30);
        startPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        //Jpanel for images
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setBounds(0, 30, 1280, 720);
        //Impostazioni label e ImageIcon
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Image on JLabel!");
        label.setBackground(Color.black);
        label.setForeground(Color.white);

        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel( "test", new ImageIcon( "2.png" ), JLabel.LEFT );




        /* put every jlabel to jpanel and put my jpanel to a container ; */
        startPanel.add(imageLabel);
        imagePanel.add(imageLabel);
        pannello.add(imagePanel);
        pannello.add(label);

        Container con = finestra.getContentPane();

        con.add(pannello);
        con.add(imagePanel);
        con.add(startPanel);
        }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new DON();
   }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: check the path of your image

Comment: I've put my image in the same folder of the java file, did I write it bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a problem with the location of your image file.

To fix it,I suggest this method.

```
new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("2.png"))
```

Make sure to clean the build and then rebuild before running.

Or you can use the path starting from ***src*** folder

```
new ImageIcon("src/..../2.png") //put your correct path
```

**EDIT:**

You have to put `finestra.setVisible(true);` at the last line of the constructor `DON()` , otherwise you will get a black screen (as you already mentioned in the deleted answer)